# Configure Ubuntu Server 17.04 as WebServer with Static IP address

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2, php

I'm a completely newbie in Ubuntu server as well generally in system administration.

I would like to run my PC as a **WebServer** so have already installed *Ubuntu Server 17.04.*

I'm trying to prepare everything running with a **Static IP address** (already got it!) so to have remote access on the Server, would like to install [vesta control panel](https://vestacp.com/) to maintain my server and install all I need to work on to develop and Host Own WebSites as Web Based Applications (php, javascript, java etc...)

I've already done some work with `sudo apt-get` installing **Apache2**, **php**, **MySql**, **SSH**, but I guess there are some other things to consider. Can reach the server *locally*, but got stuck in configuring Network connection with my Static IP Address.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57412/discussion-on-question-by-gianni-configure-ubuntu-server-17-04-as-webserver-with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: **Static IP Address:**

1. Check your Firewall Status with `sudo ufw status` and you should get something like this list:

   ```
   To                         Action      From
   --                         ------      ----
   38/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
   80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
   80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
   38/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
   80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
   80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
   ```

   *On how to add, remove and edit `ufw` Ports follow these [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server) or this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html)*
2. Setup Port Forwarding on your Router, *example*:

   Static IP Address [**x.x.x.x**] -TO-> Server Local IP Address [**192.168.1.101**]

*If you don't know your assigned IP is just place this in terminal: `ifconfig -a`*

```
enp6s7: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.38  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a02:121f:fdb:0:211:43ff:fee0:b54  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::211:43ff:fee0:b54  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:11:43:e0:0b:54  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 84296  bytes 38047233 (38.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 37523  bytes 4411985 (4.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 997  bytes 93756 (93.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 997  bytes 93756 (93.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

3. Configure ports on SSH with : `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

   on line 13 Uncomment `Port` deleting `#` (we opening port 38 here)

   ```
   Port 38
   #AddressFamily any
   #ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
   #ListenAddress ::
   ```

   Save with `ctrl+x` save with `y`
4. connect noe remotely from your client with:
   `ssh://your_username_here@your_static_ip_here:your_port_number_here`